# How to avoid copy assignment operator c++ for a shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Consider the line below to create an object `foo` of class `creature`:

```cpp
foo = creature(choice);
```

This creates a temporary `creature` object before assigning it to `foo`. Which also means that the destructor will be called. If I don't want this to happen, and I don't want to implement a copy assignment operator, I will then create it with this:

```cpp
creature foo(choice);
```

How do I do it likewise for the line below? Again, creature's destructor will get called, and I want to avoid this.

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<creature> creature_sp = std::make_shared<creature>(creature(choice));
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<creature> creature_sp = std::make_shared<creature>(choice);` ought to work. More information is required if it doesn't. In addition, you might find [Copy Elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) enlightening.

Comment: "_I don't want to implement a copy assignment operator_" - In `foo = creature(choice);` it'll use the move assignment operator (if it's not deleted) to move the data held by the temporary into `foo`.

Also, you can only initialize a variable _once_. When creating your `shared_ptr`, no destructors should be called. Since C++17, that's guaranteed.

Comment: Do this: `std::shared_ptr<creature> creature_sp = std::make_shared<creature>(choice);`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object creation part should be:

```
std::make_shared<creature>(choice);
```

The `make_shared` uses perfect forwarding to forward the arguments to the constructor of the template type -- this is the whole reason for `make_shared` existing.

Also you can avoid the possibility of typoes ([DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) by using `auto`:

```
auto creature_sp = std::make_shared<creature>(choice);
```